# Simple example of Andoroid's state changing

Tags: android

Can someone share an easy example to see how people are overriding methods called during application lifecycle. How to save and restore the data of activities. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar thing some time back. But these links ought to get you started. There really is no easy way of finding out except trial and error i suppose.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

A very interesting link this one. A must see if you would:

http://www.technicaljar.com/?p=517

Whoops. Missed the most interesting link yet. My bad

http://grail.cba.csuohio.edu/~matos/notes/cis-493/lecture-notes/Android-Chapter03-Life-Cycle.pdf